# Optimizing view controller transition time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to understand how to minimize my transition time between my view controllers.

For some reason, segment switching to one of my controllers takes 1204.0 ms.

In instruments it is telling me that this method is taking 964.0 ms.

```
 - (void)goToNextContentViewController
{

    self.index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil];
    SABaseContentViewController *queueViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Queue"];
    queueViewController.rootViewController = self;

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[queueViewController]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     }];
}
```

Specifically when I select a segmented control.

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0) {
        [self goToPreviousContentViewController];
    }
    else{
        [self goToNextContentViewController];
    }
}
```

I am pushing to a tableViewController that is loading data that I am populating from a singleton. Any ideas why this is happening? My other segment tab loads the view controller at a much faster speed with the same method.

The strangest part is that the view loads pretty fast, ONLY when the tableView in the controller I am pushing to is populated with 3 or less objects from my SingletonArray. If the array is 3 or greater, it will load at a speed of 1000+ms....

Here is my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.tableView setEditing:YES];
    self.editSelected = NO;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:@"songEnded" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: When transition time is more, the common place where you have messed up is your `viewDidLoad`. Check it once!

Comment: Posted update with my viewDidLoad @GaneshSomani

Comment: looks really ok to me... Just for a trial purpose, can you initialize datasource and delegate for table in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: no change in speed @GaneshSomani